# Mapping of a series

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic, pattern-recognition

I have been trying for a logic for mapping a series
which is

`8->15   maps to 0-7
24->31  maps t0 8-15
40->47  maps to 16-23`

and so on . I am given this sequence and a constant number =8. I can do subtraction, addition, multiplication , division etc. with series numbers and constant number.
Trying hard since yesterday, can anyone tell me it is even possible?

Comment: You might have an easier time doing the reverse: e.g. http://oeis.org/A115419

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each number in your sequence on the left are precisely those numbers with a $1$ in the third digit (*counting from the right*) when represented in binary.  (See http://oeis.org/A115419)

By considering the binary representation of your numbers, determine the result of your "mapping" by deleting the third digit.  (*By deleting, I mean completely remove it, not just replace it with zero*).

E.g. $8$ which was $\color{red}{1}00_2$ becomes $00_2$ which is $0$ in decimal, $24$ which was $1\color{red}{1}00_2$ becomes $100_2$ which is $8$ in decimal,  $29$ which was $11\color{red}{1}01_2$ becomes $1101_2$ which is $13$ in decimal, etc...

If you insist on this being notated with symbols rather than words, then we have $n\mapsto 8\lfloor\frac{n}{16}\rfloor + n-8\lfloor\frac{n}{8}\rfloor$

Comment: could you tell me method theorm you used to find